# How to paste special values in google scripts?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this cell that has a formula which constantly updates its value. If the value gets to a specified number (For example: 10), I want to record its value on a different cell (For example: B2).

I'm guessing something like this would work:

```
If (Cell A2 = 10) {
       change cell B2 into 10
}
```

I tried it inputting this formula on B2:

```
=if(A2=10,"10","")
```

The problem is, once A2 changes again, B2 changes as well. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: No, at least not just using formulas. You can look through https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events to find an event that will trigger when the right changes are detected to your target cell and change the corresponding value on B2.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
=if(A2=10,"10",if (A2<> 10,"10"))
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the problem. Try pasting this in the script editor.

```
function onEdit(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
 var target = ss.getRange("A1").getValue()//Sets the Target value i.e. 10
 var r = ss.getRange(2,1) //gets A2 range
 var val = r.getValue()// gets A2 value (in my test A2 is =F1 which is a calculated value(=D1*E1).
  if(val==target){ //If the value = the target value
  ss.getRange(2,2).setValue(val) //write the value to B2
  }
  }
```

Comment: That'll just set it to 10 regardless of its initial value which is not what OP asked.